# Macro run time error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a peice of code that filters a column for zero values and returns the rowcount. I tried looping over different columns.this macro works well with small input.
But I have an excel sheet with 160106 rows. I want to run my macro on this . I am getting a run 1004 error.I found the following link which kind of explains the problem
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210684

But I am not able to resolve it. Could anyone please help me. I am pasting my macro below

my sample file is in
http://rapidshare.com/files/457005707/data1.xlsx
it is a 96mb file

```
Option Explicit
Sub findrcn()
Dim wsStart As Worksheet
Dim sWord As String
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim k As String
Dim Final As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim oBook As Workbook





Set wsStart = ActiveSheet
'this loop is to check if a sheet exists
    For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    k = Worksheets(j).Name
    If UCase(k) = UCase("Analysis") Then
        lastrow = ((Sheets("Analysis").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1)
    Else
        lastrow = 0
    End If

    Next j
    MsgBox "finished checking the sheets"
i = 1
For Each rng In Range("A1:B1").Columns
        sWord = Replace(rng.Address(RowAbsolute:=False), "$", "")   ''Now I am trying to loop over all the columns

    If lastrow = 0 Then
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Adding a new sheet
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Analysis"
            wsStart.AutoFilterMode = False

                With wsStart
                    .Range(sWord).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="=0" 'if my column contains a 0 in it filter that

                        With .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        Final = .Count 'get the count of the number of rows after the filter
                        RowCount = Final - 1
                        End With

                       Sheets("Analysis").Range("A") = RowCount 'paste it in the analysis tab
                       Sheets("Analysis").Range("B") = (Range(sWord))

                End With
                wsStart.AutoFilterMode = False
                MsgBox "Trust in the Lord with all your heart and lean not on your own understanding; In all your ways acknowledge Him, and He will make your paths straight." & vbCrLf & "Proverbs 3:5" & vbCrLf & "                        SUCCESSFULLY     COMPLETED!!!"

    Else

        wsStart.AutoFilterMode = False

                lastrow = ((Sheets("Analysis").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1)
                With wsStart
                    .Range(sWord).AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="=0" 'if my column contains a 0 in it filter that
                        With .AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        Final = .Count
                        RowCount = Final - 1 ' to account for column name
                        End With

                       Sheets("Analysis").Range("A" & lastrow) = RowCount 'paste it in the analysis tab
                       Sheets("Analysis").Range("B" & lastrow) = (Range(sWord))

                End With
                wsStart.AutoFilterMode = False


    End If
i = i + 1
Next rng
```

Answer (score 0):

Although that knowledgebase article is talking about copying sheets and you're copying cells, you could follow its advice and save and close your worksheets periodically.

Answer (score 0):

On first glance there seem to be a much simpler solution: use the `CountIf` function

eg assuming your data is on Sheet2, on your Analysis sheet put in a cell `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,0)`
this gives the count of cell = 0 in column A

If you need this in VBA for other reasons, you can use somthing like

```
Set r = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A")
z = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "0")
```